# How do I make this Powershell just give a list of unique nouns?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-Command -Type Cmdlet |where-object Source -ne AWSPowerShell | Format-List -GroupBy Noun > C:\windows\temp\commandnouns.txt
```

Just learning powershell, I'm 13 but can't figure out how to filter for unique nouns and just have it list the nouns without the rest of the properties.

```
Get-Command -Type Cmdlet |where-object Source -ne AWSPowerShell | Format-List -GroupBy Noun > C:\windows\temp\commandnouns.txt
```

Currently get this:

Noun: AppvClientConnectionGroup

Name             : Add-AppvClientConnectionGroup
CommandType      : Cmdlet
Definition       : Add-AppvClientConnectionGroup

Path             :
AssemblyInfo     :
DLL              :
HelpFile         :
ParameterSets    : {}
ImplementingType :
Verb             : Add
Noun             : AppvClientConnectionGroup

etc...

What I want is this (Do I need to learn psobject? I'm not there yet)
commandnouns.txt... with unique nouns in 5.1 powershell

```
computer
event
appxpackage
member 
etc...
```

Comment: Please add error messages, if you have any (in TEXT format, not as picture), and please make it **more clear** what your input, and expected output is.

Comment: If I do `get-command -noun` and press tab, there's 840 completions.  It depends on what modules you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the nouns from two of the modules that are loaded when powershell starts.  That's still 89 nouns.

```
get-command -module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management,Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility |
  select noun | sort -u noun
```

Don't forget that tab completion is your friend.  See all completions at once:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler tab complete # default is TabCompleteNext
get- <#tab#>
```

Comment: Thank you, are select and sort aliases of select-object and sort-object?  edit research myself yes they are. Thank you again kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
Get-Content ./commandnouns.txt
noun1
noun2
noun2
noun3
noun3
noun3
```

and you get above results, then getting the unique items can be done like this:

```
Get-Content ./commandnouns.txt | Sort-Object -Unique 
noun1
noun2
noun3
```

Comment: Thank you that should work once I get just a list of nouns

Answer (score 0):

Believe the below may be what you are looking for:

```
Get-Command | where-object Source -ne AWSPowerShell | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Noun -Unique -ErrorAction Silent | Sort-Object -Descending -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > C:\windows\temp\commandnouns.txt
```